# Debugging node.js with Express Framework: Troubleshooting missing res.end

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The Express node.js server application I'm currently developing will sometimes go off into the void and stops returning requests. I very much suspect somewhere in it I am doing something that is ultimately skipping a res.end that I need to be doing.

Does anyone have any tips or tricks on how to best go about looking for where I'm missing the res.end (assuming that's the problem)? Is there anyway to view the currently open requests in real time in the node event loop?

When things hang up, everything is still running in that Express will still accept incoming requests. And, these requests are logged to the console via express.logger just fine. But, the request is never returned to the client and no error is being thrown.

Thank you in advance for your thoughts.

Follow-up:

There doesn't seem to be much documentation on node's debug mode beyond the raw API docs. I did find [this article](http://www.100percentjs.com/best-way-debug-node-js/) which seems to provide a good overview of several options. But, there doesn't seem to be the kind of thing I was thinking of for watching the event loop, something a la [vtop's process list](http://parall.ax/vtop).

More Follow-up:

Yesterday, Daniel Hood published [Debugging in Node.js](http://fullstackforum.com/software/2014/08/28/debugging-in-nodejs-part-1-the-basics/) stating that, "The state of debugging node.js apps has always been a bit unfortunate..." So, perhaps my question is not so silly as to merit down votes as it might seem. Anyway, in his next article he promises to cover some tools for debugging asynchronous operations.

Comment: You can start Node [in debug mode](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html), perhaps through a tool like [`node-debug`](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector#quick-start), that can allow you to set breakpoints and step through the code as it executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the last article you mentioned.  If you need to debug async stuff, I'll be going over things like long stack traces (modules such [longjohn](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/npmawesome-full-stack-traces-with-longjohn/)), the [try-catch module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/trycatch), and things like zones/domains.  Hopefully those links will be of some help (might be a week before I write part 2).

However, for your particular issue, have you tried setting a breakpoint at some known location and stepping through the process?  This way you can just watch how the app is executed, and maybe find where some function is returning nothing when it should be returning the req/res object.

If it isn't very reproducible, maybe some simple [logging](https://www.npmjs.org/package/basic-logger) would be helpful.